# How to rotate the block every time you click on the button?

Tags: html, css, svg

More precisely, the rotation of the block does not work.

At the moment, the block turns once, and I want to turn every time i click in both directions.

how to do it ?

```js
var now = 10
$('.left').click(function() {

  $(".d").css('transform', 'rotate (' + now + 'deg)');
});
```

```css
.r {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 20px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.d {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 20px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 230px;
}

.parent {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  position: relative;
}

.r,
.d {
  position: absolute;
}

.d {
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.btns {
  display: table;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

button {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="r"></div>
    <div class="d"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="btns">
    <button class="left">+</button>
    <button class="right">-</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

At the very beginning I wanted to make such a regulator as in the screenshot.

but since there is no great knowledge in JS and I decided to do it in HTML and CSS + jQuery

wanted to use svg but I don't know how to change it

hope for your help

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep a running total in `now` so that you can keep incrementing. For example:

```
var now = 0;

$('.left').click(function() {
  now += 10;
  $(".d").css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
});

$('.right').click(function() {
  now -= 10;
  $(".d").css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
});
```

As another person has just pointed out, your spaces between `rotate` and `(` were also breaking it.

Here's a CodePen if you need it: https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/MZgqop

Comment: why it is not working ...  [fiddle](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/jXNpJO?editors=0010)

Comment: It does not work because of with spaces in the `'rotate (' + now + 'deg)')`

Answer (score 2):

I think the Problem is with unnecessary`spaces` that I remove I hope to help you.

```
var now = 10;

    $('.left').click(function() {
      now += 10;
      $(".d").css('transform', 'rotate('+now+'deg)');
    });

    $('.right').click(function() {
      now -= 10;
      $(".d").css('transform', 'rotate('+now+'deg)');
    });
```

Comment: your example doesn't work either  [fiddle](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/jXNpJO?editors=0010)

Comment: @UbuntuUser you missed the first line `var now = 10;`

Answer (score 2):

In this case you have to increase or decrease `10 deg` again and again here is an example:

```
$(function(){
      var now = 10,
      count = 0;
      $('.left').click(function() {
        rotate( count + 1);
      });
      $('.right').click(function() {
        rotate( count - 1);
      });

      function rotate(new_count) {
        var rotatePx = ((new_count) * (now));
        $(".d").css('transform', 'rotate('+ rotatePx +'deg)');
        count = new_count;
      }

    });
```